# how can I make a sym link that is available anywhere (via command line) in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, command-line, powershell

In Ubuntu I've been using:

`cd ~/theApp`

to get to a frequently used directory. Is there a Windows equivalent? I'm looking for a sym link (via `mklink`) that is available no matter where I am. Would placing a sym link somewhere in my PATH do the trick? I need it to be accessible via Powershell as well.

Answer (score 1):

In Linux the '~' (tilde) character is just a shortcut to the users home directory. The equivalent in Windows is the environment variable '%USERPROFILE%'. You might be able to assign  that something more convenient, such as '~', but I don't have my windows box running to test that out for you.

Last time I checked Powershell didn't have mklink, but it should follow links set by cmd.exe.

Comment: you can do a mklink in powershell with `cmd /c mklink "wd" c:\dev\code`